# What's the use of `component1` to `component5` for Kotlin Collection?

Tags: kotlin, collections

In Kotlin document https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/component1.html
There's `component1` till `component5`. I'm a little lost what are the use cases of them?

I thought we could essentially `mylist.get[0]` for `mylist.component1`. It is shorter and more extensible.
It seems redundant to have such `component1` etc. Did I miss out any detail?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

These allow [destructuring declarations](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/multi-declarations.html).

Further down the page linked in the question, it explains that the corresponding `component1()` and `component2()` methods for Map entries allow you to use destructuring declarations with them.  It's the same for collections and arrays.

If you need the first few elements of a collection, you can assign them to named variables like this:

```
val (first, second, third, fourth, fifth) = myList;
```

Similarly, if you pass a collection as a lambda parameter, it can split it easily:

```
myList.let{ (first, second, third) ->
    // …
}
```

This feature is a little less useful for collections and arrays than it is for data classes or maps, as there's no guarantee that it's long enough; the above would give an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` if not.  Or if it's longer, the excess elements are ignored.  But in cases where you can be sure of the length, it can be a little more concise.

Comment: Thanks. Great explanation. https://medium.com/@elye.project/kotlin-has-4-ways-to-access-the-collection-element-1cf20cfdd0ed